# MySQL In-place upgrade creates a new instance instead of upgrading the existing one

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

I am doing an in-place upgrade from mysql 5.7.26 to 5.7.33. I have done from 5.6 to 5.7 for serveral hosts and did not face this issue.

Followed below steps

1. Took a VM snapshot and mysqldump as well.
2. systemctl stop mysqld
3. removed mysql 5.7.26 rpms
4. yum install mysql-community-common-5.7.33-1.el7.x86_64
5. yum install mysql-community-libs-5.7.33-1.el7.x86_64
6. yum install mysql-community-libs-compat-5.7.33-1.el7.x86_64
7. yum install mysql-community-client-5.7.33-1.el7.x86_64
8. yum install mysql-community-server-5.7.33-1.el7.x86_64
9. systemctl start mysqld

After installed 5.7.33 rpms, when i tried to run mysql_upgrade ,I realized my password is'nt working and then when i checked i saw a new empty /etc/my.cnf file and new instance under /var/lib/mysql. I could still see my actual data directory intact.

Why is this issue because i never faced it before. If i replace the empty my.cnf with my actual my.cnf and restart the mysqld service, will it be a solution to my problem.

Thanks

Comment: Dont know why this issue. Removing 5.7.26 rpms actually renames the /etc/my.cnf to /etc/my.cnf.rpmsave. Installing 5.7.33 rpms creates a plain new /etc/my.cnf . So when i start mysqld, it creates a new datadir in /var/lib/mysql. After removing old rpms, i renamed /etc/my.cnf.rpmsave to /etc/my.cnf and started mysqld and ran mysql_upgrade. All good now.  I upgraded to mysql 5.7.33 in many servers, did not face the issue anywhere. only difference i see is my.cnf is owned by mysql in working servers while it is owned by root in current scenario.

Comment: Copy your Comment into an Answer.  (It will give you some more reputation points.)

Comment: Check the changelogs between 5.7.26 and .33; they may point out an issue with "in-place".

Comment: Hi Rick What do u mean by changelogs. does mysql upgrade summary captured anywhere? This is 5.7.33 so mysql_upgrade is not run by mysql server itself while starting mysqld ( I had to explicitly run mysql_upgrade utility in this case). So i dont see any message related to upgrade in error log.

Comment: The 7 links (.27 to .33) are here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/5.7/en/ (Reading all will be tedious and boring.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont know why this issue. Removing 5.7.26 rpms actually renames the /etc/my.cnf to /etc/my.cnf.rpmsave. Installing 5.7.33 rpms creates a plain new /etc/my.cnf . So when i start mysqld, it creates a new datadir in /var/lib/mysql. After removing old rpms, i renamed /etc/my.cnf.rpmsave to /etc/my.cnf and started mysqld and ran mysql_upgrade. All good now. I upgraded to mysql 5.7.33 in many servers, did not face the issue anywhere. only difference i see is my.cnf is owned by mysql in working servers while it is owned by root in current scenario